# Posting objects from Array to .NET core 2 API from Angular 7

Tags: .net, angular, api, asp.net-core

I've been struggling with trying to post data from an array to a .net core 2 API. the user has a grid with check-boxes and on each check, it adds the row to the array.  however when i attempt to post the data, it's coming in null on the back-end.  i've made posts to api's successfully in the past using reactive forms, but that was when it was just one set of values filled out by the user, i need to send prefilled data objects without forms.

.NET API Controller :

```
[HttpPost("api/updateBillingRecords")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<BillingModel[]>> UpdateBillingRecords([FromBody] BillingModel updatedBillingRecords)
        {
            var incomingRecords =  await kiraBillingService.UpdateBillingRecordsAsync(updatedBillingRecords);
            return Ok("RECORDS UPDATED");
        }
```

Angular Component :

```
 doNotBill(i) {
  var index = this.doNotBillRecords.indexOf(i);

  if (index === -1) {

    this.doNotBillRecords.push(i);
  } else {

    this.doNotBillRecords.splice(index, 1);
  }


  // test if records are being added and removed accordingly
  console.log(`Dynamic Data: ${this.doNotBillRecords.values}`);

}
```

Sending filled array to api:

```
updateBilling() {
    this.billingService.updateBillingRecords(this.doNotBillRecords).subscribe();
  }
```

Angular Service:

```
updateBillingRecords(billingRecord): Observable<BillingRecord[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post<BillingRecord[]>(this.updateBillingRecordsAPIUrl, billingRecord, { headers: headers });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should modify the server parameter to accept an array as you send array from angular .
please try to change the parameter accepted to be

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<BillingModel[]>> UpdateBillingRecords([FromBody] BillingModel[] updatedBillingRecords)
```

Comment: Thank you!  this works now, i can't believe i missed the fact that i needed to absorb the incoming data as a c# array... 'Doh!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use JSON parsing ?

Angular

```
updateBillingRecords(billingRecord): Observable<BillingRecord[]> {
       const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
       return this.http.post<BillingRecord[]>(this.updateBillingRecordsAPIUrl, JSON.stringify(billingRecord), { headers: headers });
}
```

And you use Newtonsoft JSON library to get your array

```
BillingMode[] updated = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BillingMode[]>("your body").ToArray();
```

Comment: it is my understanding that from angular 4+ there is no need to parse JSON as this happens automatically, please let me know if this correct?

Comment: I learned something today :D. I knew angular automatically parses HTTP response, but not that it also parses request :O.